# How do i debug a problem with rsyslog to remote server?

Tags: remote-server, rsyslog

I am having about 15 servers that send their syslog to a common logserver, all servers are redhat7.7, so the rsyslog is a recent version (8.24). 
The normal log get transfered to the common server OK, but then there are some application logs that are watched with the imfile module, and my problem is that only some of them are transfered correctly, but others are not transfered, or there are days, where logs are missing for hours, and then are OK the rest of the day.
How can I debug this problem, I can show a small portion of the custom log definition:

```
$InputFileName /var/log/log-compression.log
$InputFileTag log-compression-log
$InputFileStateFile stat-log-compression-log
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local2
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

There are about 20 such sections, and some of them work, and others not, and the syntax is exactly the same, it is deployed with ansible.

Comment: Make sure all the `$InputFileStateFile` files have different names, or better still remove these lines, see [imfile module](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html).  How are you sending the data to the server? udp, tcp, or relp?

Comment: The transfer is by tcp, but I am thinking of changing to relp.

Comment: Ohh, I just found: https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/3468 which looks like it could be the problem.